# É recomendável explicitar todas as variáveis?

Tags: python, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome

Essa é uma dúvida quanto a legibilidade do código ou se há algum padrão de estilo quanto a isso.

Bem, o [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) nos indica que

> Explicit is better than implicit.

mas como interpretar isso?

Pense nas seguintes abordagens:

### Abordagem 1:

```
class TicketInfos:
    ...
    ...

    def create_sheet(self):
        client_name = self._get_client_name()
        wb = Workbook(f'Tickets - {client_name}.xlsx')
        ...
        ...
```

### Abordagem 2:

```
class TicketInfos:
    ...
    ...

    def create_sheet(self):
        wb = Workbook(f'Tickets - {self._get_client_name()}.xlsx')
        ...
        ...
```

É recomendável que eu siga a primeira abordagem, explicitando a variável `client_name`? Eu, particularmente, prefiro seguir a segunda abordagem, uma vez que o nome da função `_get_client_name()` é bem autoexplicativa.

No entanto, eu sempre tento explicitar uma variável se vou usá-la para chamar outra função. Ou seja, eu prefiro fazer:

```
class _CustomValues:
    ...
    ...

    def get_impact_value(self):         
        def _get_impact_value(classification):
                ...
                ...

        impact_classification = self._get_custom_item(self.impact_id)
        return _get_impact_value(impact_classification)
```

ao invés de

```
class _CustomValues:
    ...
    ...

    def get_impact_value(self):         
        def _get_impact_value(classification):
                ...
                ...

        return _get_impact_value(self._get_custom_item(self.impact_id))
```

O que é recomendado?

Comment: Eu utilizo a primeira abordagem para reduzir a linha de código, pois às vezes, a linha acaba saindo da área do editor. Além disso, é muito mais legível a primeira abordagem tanto para você como para a sua equipe. 
Entretanto, há casos em que a segunda abordagem é melhor, como por exemplo, quando você possui uma função pequena com poucos parâmetros. É muito melhor não explicitar a variável neste caso.

Comment: Além da questão da linha ficar mais comprida no segundo caso, você pode eventualmente querer validar a variável  `client_name` (pra garantir por exemplo que não tem nenhum caractere inválido). Então essa validação você colocaria em uma linha entre `client_name = ...` e `wb = ...`. Claro que nesse exemplo não é nenhum sufoco modificar a segunda versão pela primeira, mas a ideia é que tendo o código disposto por mais linhas simplifica na hora de adicionar funcionalidade em um ponto específico da função.

Comment: Eu acho que as hipóteses que não cabem na pergunta. A questão é pura e simplesmente sobre legibilidade, não sobre tamanho da linha ou qualquer eventual teste. As abordagens foram exemplos para exemplificar o que falei na primeira linha: legibilidade e padrão de código. Se o retorno de `_get_client_name()` for necessário em algum outro lugar, se atrapalhar a ['regra'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) de 79 caracteres por linha ou algum teste posterior eu penso que a variável deve ser explicitada. De qualquer jeito, obrigado pelas respostas!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regras amplas, ambíguas e vagas, ajudam a pensar sobre o assunto, mas não servem como algo definitivo do que deve ser feito. Esta regra não diz o que deve ser explícito. A regra é quebrada o tempo todo em muitos pontos da linguagem, em alguns não, claro. Nem sempre é fácil achar o ponto de equilíbrio do que deve ser explícito ou não. Se for tudo ou nada fica complicado.

Me lembro uma vez que um professor pediu um trabalho para fazer um código onde todas funções fossem quebradas na operação mais simples possível, eu questionei. Eu entreguei de propósito um código que era praticamente um Assembly, cada função só fazia uma única operação mais simples possível, nunca duas ou mais. Então fora fazer alguma sacanagem o certo é olhar o contexto, ganhar experiência, pensar sobre o assunto e decidir caso a caso.

Se levar a regra às últimas consequências terá que fazer o que eu acabei de descrever com variáveis, cada operação simples deve estar guardada em uma variável, você fará isto? Eu acho bobagem.

Uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) deve ser usada principalmente: a) para guardar um dado temporariamente para ser usado depois; b) porque precisa dele por mais tempo ou porque ele será usado mais de uma vez. Nada impede usar a variável para outras coisas, inclusive há uma recomendação de usar uma variável para documentar melhor o que está fazendo e assim evitar um comentário dizendo o que faz ou deixar sem nada e não ficar claro o que é isto. É disso que está falando, mas é uso secundário da variável.

No exemplo o que essa variável acrescentou? Pra mim nada. Ela essencialmente reproduz o nome do método que está chamando, não documenta nada. Que vantagem tem isso? Tudo o que faz no código colocando ou retirando precisa ter uma vantagem, mesmo que não seja funcionalidade, você precisa saber justificar porque fez aquilo, não pode fazer por fazer, ou porque alguém disse que deve fazer, esse alguém não está escrevendo seu código e não será essa pessoa que sofrerá as dores.

Você está no caminho correto. Algumas pessoas podem discordar, mas eu perco o respeito por quem o fizer :P Lembrando que estou falando deste caso.

O segundo caso apresentado na pergunta já é mais complicado e precisaria entender melhor o contexto. Aí já gera mais polêmica porque a variável gera uma informação nova e pode ser útil para deixar mais legível. Não sei se é tão necessário assim.

Python é uma linguagem de *script* então tem duas coisas a se pensar, primeiro que *scripts* não deveriam ser tão complicados assim, então isso não deveria ser tão necessário. Por outro lado por ser *script* a performance não importa, então criar uma variável à toa não vai prejudicar muito. Em muitas linguagens criar uma variável até some do código, mas em Python não e a criação de uma variável tem um custo mais alto que a maioria das linguagens (não *script*).

Eu fico bem em cima do muro aí e acho que dizer vai aqui ou ali cai muito em opinião. Eu usaria um padrão diferente dependendo da linguagem ou tipo do projeto. Em Python eu não criaria a variável, mas eu só usaria Python para coisas muito simples e não para coisas complexas como muita gente faz, pra mim seria a ferramenta errada.

[image: Cavalo dentro de um carro vermelho com a cabeça pra fora andando pelas ruas]

Se estiver em equipe siga o que a equipe manda, se você é quem define o que fazer crie um padrão e o siga (crie regras menos vagas).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Boa resposta, programar é igual pintar um quadro, você expressa sua arte ali; Tente fazer da forma mais legível possível, para facilitar a manutenção no futuro